# Postgres 9.3 partitioning table update out of memory error

Tags: postgresql

I have a master table with more than 100 columns. I have created child tables using inheritance concept in Postgres 9.1.

Now I am trying to migrate to 9.3 Postgres Version. When I am updating a particular row in partition table it is showing out of Memory Error. But in postgres 9.1 Version it is not throwing that error.

I have found open bug in postgres for 9.3.5 version

http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/alpine.LRH.2.11.1411080127430.2920@calx115.ast.cam.ac.uk

I dont know whether it is a postgres bug or our database architecture fault

My partition table has 30000rows

My Child tables count is 610

My Postgres.conf file settings are default settings

Could any one suggest me possible solution.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: I wonder why you think you need to partition your table for just 30000 rows.

Comment: Why do you create 610 child tables when a single table has only 30000 records? In my situation that would be an almost empty table.... 610 tables with 30000 records each, less than 20 million records, less then we process on a single day. And we have partitions per month. Default configuration settings are almost always a problem, just good enough to get started. You have to optimize it for your workload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To quote Tom Lane from [the previous mail](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/14421.1415396018@sss.pgh.pa.us):

> The inheritance infrastructure is only designed to support maybe 100
>   child tables.  If we ever get around to implementing a hard-wired
>   partitioning scheme, it's possible that multiple thousands of partitions
>   could be practical, but it isn't today.  Sorry.

It seems that your 610 child tables are way too many to work reliably with the current postgres architecture. There is little you can do here yourself, except to drastically reduce the number of child tables and use other means to structure your data.

Comment: But in postgres 9.1 and 9.2 i did n't face this kind of error. I am confused why this error is coming in 9.3 version.